# Varbinary Data copying issue

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, varbinary

I have a table with a varbinary data column, I want to copy the data to another table but when I try I get errors even though I have set the receiving column to varbinary.

I am obviously missing something here, can anyone help?

regards

Comment: Yes, you are obviously missing something, at least the error message given sql server, and query on which it gives you.

Comment: ah ha, good point Hamlet

Comment: Just doing a straight copy and paste from one field to another give error

The changed value in this cell was not recognised as valid .NET Framework Data Type:Byte []

Comment: Are you using some edit top n rows grid to copy data between tables? Hint: SQL Server is not a spreadsheet. Why don't you try writing an INSERT or UPDATE statement?

Comment: Hi aaron I was using edit, stupidly haven't tried insert or update

Comment: I think the issue I have is that I cant see the data as its displayed as <binary data>

Comment: Ok have changed my method and am now using an update statement. I know get the error The multi-part identifier "rfidsink.dbo.TagEvents.TagId" could not be bound.

UPDATE [rfidsink].[dbo].[AssetMaster]
   SET [RFIDcode] = [rfidsink].[dbo].[Tagevents].[TagId]
 WHERE [rfidsink].[dbo].[AssetMaster].[AssetCode]='Defibulator';
GO